# Media queries not relating to pixels on website

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm building a responsive site but when I resize the window the media queries aren't corresponding with my screen resolution, so for instance,
**@media screen and (min-width:640px) and (max-width: 800px)**  is resulting in these design elements to be when the screen is **above 800 pixels** and when I'm at **700 pixels** my designs are being set to **`@media screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width:640px)`** for some reason. Does anyone know why this could be happening?

```
Update: The max-width 640px media query is being set to my screen at over 700 pixels still. 

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px)  { 
.body{
    width:800px;
}
```

}

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) { 
    .body {
        width:600px;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width:640px) { 
    .body {
        width:480px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:400px) {

.body {
    width:260px;
}
```

}

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

To start troubleshooting, double check that in the head of your document you have

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Let me know how you get on.

**Edit**

Thanks for the extra code. Check out [this working example](http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/FE5gS/). The CSS and the order of the media queries is below:

```
/* set default  */
.body{
    width:800px;
  }

@media screen and (max-width:400px) {
  .body {
    width:260px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width:640px) { 
    .body {
      width:480px;
    }
}



@media screen and (min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 800px) { 
    .body {
       width:600px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 801px) and (max-width: 1024px)  { 
  .body{
    width:800px;
   }
}
```

Comment: Yep that's in my header

Comment: but it's still displaying the changes at incorrect resolutions

Comment: @user3219182  you could validate your css to make sure there isn't a syntax error that's causing problems( like a closing } in your 800-1024px media query). It would also help if you could post a URL

Comment: yeah sorry unable to post a url at the moment

Comment: One thing to remember with media queries is that order matters. To get the results you want, make sure the default width for your body class is set before all your media queries. @user3219182

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realise that was necessary if a width is set at each width.

Comment: Sorry thought that fixed it but it is still off. I'll update my code